# Running an age and gender detector in Python and getting errors in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

While running the following code:

```
genderProto = "gender_deploy.prototxt"
genderModel = "gender_net.caffemodel"
ageNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(ageModel, ageProto)

genderList = ['Male', 'Female']

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1, (227, 227), MODEL_MEAN_VALUES, swapRB=False)
genderNet.setInput(blob)
genderPreds = genderNet.forward()
gender = genderList[genderPreds[0].argmax()]
print("Gender Output : {}".format(genderPreds))
print("Gender : {}".format(gender))
```

I got the following error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e65b55769f89> in <module>
      1 genderProto = "gender_deploy.prototxt"
      2 genderModel = "gender_net.caffemodel"
----> 3 ageNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(ageModel, ageProto)
      4 
      5 genderList = ['Male', 'Female']

error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-wv7rsg8n/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "age_deploy.prototxt" in function 'ReadProtoFromTextFile'
```

What could be the reason for this??

Comment: "Can't open age_deploy.prototxt"? I would say the file isn't there.